# <p:commandButton> with icon image not showing

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml, firebug

I have been struggling this for a while. I am using primefaces 3.5. I have a command button with icon attribute. But the image seems not showing. I am not sure if I put the image url correctly. I tried a few path. But still not working. In firebug I can see the icon.

My image residing on /BelsizeWeb/WebContent/theme/primefaces-aristo/images
CSS residing on /BelsizeWeb/WebContent/theme/primefaces-aristo

**theme.css**

```
.ui-icon-excel {
    background-image: url("images/toexcel.gif");
}
```

**xhtml**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
  href="#{request.contextPath}/theme/primefaces-aristo/theme.css" />

<p:commandButton type="submit"
                 styleClass="commandExButton_image" id="cr1001_command_toexcel"
                 icon="ui-icon-excel"
                 action="#{pc_Cr1001.doCr1001_command_toexcelAction}" ajax="false">
              </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Icon property will work with PrimeFaces (jQuery UI's) predifinded icon's only.

To solve your requirement there are two ways.

**1.** Using Image of p:commandButton

Modify you css class as shown below,

```
     .ui-icon-excel {
            background: url("images/toexcel.gif")  no-repeat top left !important;;
     }
```

Then use your command button as shown below,

```
<p:commandButton type="submit"
             id="cr1001_command_toexcel"
             image="ui-icon-excel"
             action="#{pc_Cr1001.doCr1001_command_toexcelAction}" ajax="false">
          </p:commandButton>
```

**2.** Use jsf h:commandButton as shown below,

```
<h:commandButton image="images/toexcel.gif"/>
```

You can ajaxify h:commandButton further

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I know what does !important means? I am confused with that.